# disable all the radio button with same name

Tags: jquery

I have a 2 set of radio button, if one of the option is selected other radio in the same group have to disabled.

```
<div class="question_container">
<p class="questions">Question about stuff?</p>  <span class="group" style="inline-block;">
    <label>
    <input id="id_radio1" class="incorrect" type="radio" name="group1" value="Answer 1" />Answer 1
    </label>
    <label>
    <input id="id_radio2" class="correct" type="radio" name="group1" value="Answer 2" />Answer 2
    </label>
    <label>
    <input id="id_radio3" class="incorrect" type="radio" name="group1" value="Answer 3" />Answer 3
    </label>
    <label>
    <input id="id_radio4" class="incorrect" type="radio" name="group1" value="Answer 4" />Answer 4
    </label>
</span>
```

Question about stuff?  
        
        Answer 1
        
        
        Answer 2
        
        
        Answer 3
        
        
        Answer 4

```
$("input[type=radio]").click(function () {
var Radio = $(this);
var GetGroup = Radio.parents(".group");
GetGroup.find("label").css({
    "background-color": "transparent"
});

if (Radio.attr("class") == 'correct') {

    Radio.parent().css({
        "background-color": "green"
    });
} else Radio.parent().css({
    "background-color": "red"
});
```

});

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abhilashrajrs/ce0nun56/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var RadioName = Radio.attr('name');
$("input[name='" + RadioName + "']").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

Comment: My i ask one more thing, how show a div on radio button select

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to the end of your click handler:

```
$('input[name=' + Radio.context.name + ']').attr("disabled",true);
```

It will disable the relevant group...

Answer (score 0):

To disable all radio's that have the same `name` attribute I use the `prop` function:

```
//disable all radios with the name 'insertyourradioname'
$('input[name=insertyourradioname]').prop('disabled', true);

//enable all radios with the name 'insertyourradioname'
$('input[name=insertyourradioname]').prop('disabled', false);
```